# Ensure that done() callback is being called in this Mocha test

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodejs-stream

Looking at other questions, can't really find the cause of the problem. I am trying to test using mocha.

```
it("Should not do the work",function(done) {
  axios
    .post("x/y",{ id:a2 })
    .then(function(res) {
      assert(false,"Should not do the work");
      done();
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
      assert.equal(HttpStatus.CONFLICT,res.status);
      done();
    });
});

it("Should do the work",function(done) {
  axios
    .post("/x/y",{ id: a1 })
    .then(function(res) {
      done();
    })
    .catch(done);
});
```

The result was:

```
√ Should not do the work (64ms)
1) Should do the work
1 passing (20s)
1 failing

1) Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Increasing the timeout didn't work.

Comment: Don't forget you can simply `return` a promise in Mocha and it will deal with it accordingly. In your first example are you sure those blocks are actually executed? I'd check that it's triggering at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can simply `return` a promise in Mocha and it will deal with it accordingly. In your first example are you sure those blocks are actually executed?

Doing an assertion may cause an exception, which can sabotage what you're trying to do. If your promise library supports it you can always:

```
it("Should not do the work",function(done) {
 axios.post("x/y",{ id:a2 })
  .then(function(res) {
    assert(false,"Should not do the work");
  })
  .catch(function(res) {
    assert.equal(HttpStatus.CONFLICT,res.status);
  })
  .finally(done);
});
```

Ensuring that should be done regardless.

Even better:

```
it("Should not do the work",function() {
  return axios.post("x/y",{ id:a2 })
    .then(function(res) {
      assert(false,"Should not do the work");
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
      assert.equal(HttpStatus.CONFLICT,res.status);
    })
});
```

Watch for doing catches on assertions and assertions in catches. A better plan might be async:

```
it("Should not do the work", async function() {
  var res = await axios.post("x/y",{ id:a2 })

  assert.equal(HttpStatus.CONFLICT,res.status);
});
```

Comment: The first example is working fine. I am facing the problem with second example

Comment: Maybe your implementation is busted because that should work.